# How to select a numeric part of nvarchar datatype field

Tags: sql-server

I want to select the numeric part of data that saved in nvarchar() datatype column in sqlserver.
The size of a character in rows doesn't same and maybe some of the rows don't have the numeric part  on the column, for example, the data format like 
    /TablePhoneHome>

or

```
<TablePhoneHome></TablePhoneHome>
```

or

```
<TablePhoneHome><Number Num="9123159834"/></TablePhoneHome>
```

or

```
<TablePhoneHome><Number Num="somthing"/></TablePhoneHome>
```

I want to select the phone number from that like :

```
09151826166-09151150374
null
9123159834
```

Comment: Is it a `varchar` Column is an `xml` column? If it's a `varchar`, why are you *not* using  the `xml` datatype which would make getting the value trivial, by use of `XQUERY`. Also, where are those expected results coming from? They don't like up with your samples?

Comment: Its nvarchar column but the format that data saved like xml .this field is a note that  have name and phone number of person but I want to export Separate
data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Assuming*** the data type is actually `xml` (and if it isn't, then you should fix your data type to be `xml`) you can easily use XQUERY to get the value:

```
SELECT YT.YourColumn.value('(/TablePhoneHome/Number/@Num)[1]','varchar(50)') AS Num
FROM YourTable YT;
```